# for i in range(len(val)): TypeError: object of type 'numpy.int64' has no len()

Tags: python, excel, pandas, selenium, numpy

I'm trying to use a for loop to enter data from, an excel spreadsheet, to an input field on a web page.  I've explored the option that NaN values could be the culprit of my error, however, I used df.replace to fix that.  Still receiving the error.  Some help would be appreciated.  My code and the full error below.

```
csv = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\Dylan\\Desktop\\6817CleanLeads1.csv')
dot_nums = list(csv.DOTNumber)

for i in (dot_nums):
    entry_box = 
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//[@id="DOTNumber"]/div[1]/input')
    entry_box.send_keys(i)
    browser.find_element_by_link_text("Search").click()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "...\test.py", line 45, in <module>
   entry_box.send_keys(i)
File "...\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 349, in send_keys
   {'text': "".join(keys_to_typing(value)),
File "...\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\utils.py", line 150, in keys_to_typing
   for i in range(len(val)):
TypeError: object of type 'numpy.int64' has no len()
```

Comment: @cricket_007  I tested before hand by sending a random number without the for loop, it worked fine.

Comment: Try: ```send_keys(i.item)```. (and if it's working, start your tour of enlightenment [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.item.html) and [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/2951); can't find better links right now)

Comment: What type of data is in `dot_nums`? The error starts at the `send_keys`, so whatever you are sending via that loop isn't the correct type

Comment: @sascha TypeError: object of type 'builtin_function_or_method' has no len()

Comment: @cricket_007 dot_nums = a column of numbers in excel.  The end goal is the for loop to go one by one down the list entering each number then scraping for the data I need.

Comment: Yes, and that is a numpy datatype... `numpy.int64` not a regular number value. I think what @sascha meant was `i.item(0)`

Comment: @cricket_007 item(0) seems to work!  However, how would I make this process repeat?  going 1 by 1 down the list of numbers?

Comment: `for i in dot_nums` should already do that. If you want to go over the **columns**, then you need a nested loop

Comment: @cricket_007 every time 1 number gets inputted I need to scrape data that the number spits out on the site, then return to the initial input screen and put in the next number.  I don't know what loop I need?

Comment: Okay... Your code isn't returning to any screen, so I don't know what you're asking for

Comment: @cricket_007 Right, I haven't gotten that far yet I'm asking if my code atm will do what I'm saying when I finish the script

Comment: I don't know. I've only answered what the error is telling you

Comment: Just don't use `pandas`? Use `csv`?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the sheet has numbers and pd is reading it as int64 instead of string that you want. The only thing that you may need is below

```
entry_box.send_keys(str(i))
```